# `core_cache` and `core_cache_tag` empty?

Tags: cache, full-page-cache

I'm trying to debug a problem with FPC on Mage EE 1.11.2.0 (the problem is related to some custom modules )

I have truncated table `core_cache` and `core_cache_tag` to have fresh data but now those table are always empty even if I refresh cache.

By the way the cache system looks to work fine

What I did is so wrong ? 
How can I regenerate the content (blob) of those table ?

I definitely miss something in the understanding of the many layers of cache magento has. ( I guess I have some mess in the local.xml )

```
<config>
  <global>
    <install>
      <date><![CDATA[Thu, 26 Jan 2012 16:09:29 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
      <key><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
      <db>
        <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
      </db>
      <default_setup>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[xxxx]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[xxxx]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[xxxx]]></dbname>
          <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
          <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
          <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
          <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
          <active>1</active>
        </connection>
      </default_setup>
    </resources>    
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't configured the database as a cache backend, you should see cache files created under var/cache at this moment. Try adding the following lines under the global tag in your app/etc/local.xml to activate the database caching:

```
<cache>
    <backend>database</backend>
</cache>
```

After that refresh your cache and remove the created cache files under var/cache/, this directory should stay empty when the database cache is used.

Comment: Better to learn where the cache is being stored than to just switch it to database storage. IMO there is no use case where database makes sense for a cache backed. If on a cluster, use a distributed memory based back end such as mmcached or Redis.